# Purescript: How to read a string from stdin and save it?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, purescript, purely-functional, spago

I'm quite new to Purescript and I am trying to process some user input (received from stdin) but my best approach is this one:

```
processInput :: String -> Effect Unit
processInput input = do
  let
    arr = split (Pattern " ") input
    player1 = unsafeIndex arr 0
    player2 = unsafeIndex arr 1
    result = checkGame player1 player2
  log $ "You typed: " <> player1 <> " " <> player2 <> ":" <> show (result)

lineHandler :: Interface -> String -> Effect Unit
lineHandler interface s  = do
  if s == "quit"
    then do
      close interface
    else do
        processInput s
        prompt interface

main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  interface <- createConsoleInterface noCompletion
  setPrompt "> " interface
  setLineHandler (lineHandler interface) interface
  prompt interface
```

In which I use the Node.ReadLine package to create an interface, ask for input and process it in another method. This is meant for a rock-scissors-paper game and I managed to obtain the result of a single move and log it to the user. But I'm stuck at adding that `result` to a total outside the lineHandler function.

Is there any other way of obtaining string input from user at `main` scope (without a lineHandler)? Or is there a way I can define a parameter `points` which accumulates over the lineHandler executions?

I thought about State but I still don't understand it very well. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to structure your program as an `Interface` from `Node.ReadLine`, you'll have to keep your game state (whatever it may be) in a mutable memory cell, which is represented by [the `Ref` type](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-refs/6.0.0/docs/Effect.Ref#t:Ref). You can create such cell with [the `new` function](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-refs/6.0.0/docs/Effect.Ref#v:new), and then read from and write to it with the `read` and `write` functions respectively.

You'll have to create the memory cell in `main` and then tunnel it through `lineHandler` to `processInput`.

```hs
processInput :: Ref.Ref Int -> String -> Effect Unit
processInput total input = do
  let
    arr = split (Pattern " ") input
    player1 = unsafePartial $ unsafeIndex arr 0
    player2 = unsafePartial $ unsafeIndex arr 1
    result = checkGame player1 player2
  currentTotal <- Ref.read total  -- Read from the cell
  let newTotal = currentTotal + 42 
  Ref.write newTotal total        -- Write new value to the cell
  log $ "You typed: " <> player1 <> " " <> player2 <> ": " <> show (result) <> ", current total is " <> show newTotal

lineHandler :: Ref.Ref Int -> Interface -> String -> Effect Unit
lineHandler total interface s  = do
  if s == "quit"
    then do
      close interface
    else do
        processInput total s
        prompt interface

main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  total <- Ref.new 0  -- Create a new memory cell with initial value of 0
  interface <- createConsoleInterface noCompletion
  setPrompt "> " interface
  setLineHandler (lineHandler total interface) interface
  prompt interface
```